# How to extract key value pairs from array of dictionaries? Swift 2.0

Tags: swift

I have an arrayOfDictionaries that has been passed to a Table View Controller from a prepareForSegue.

I want to extract the key, value pairs and hold them in a new arrayToDisplay object.

I have initialized my collection data model in my viewWillAppear but I could use some help with my loadData function and how to put data into new arrayToDisplay

Table View Controller:

```
// data model
var collection: Collection!
var arrayToDisplay = [String: AnyObject]()

// data from previous controller, data is there
var arrayOfDictionaries = [[String: AnyObject]]()

viewWillAppear()
collection = Collection(id: "", photo: "", one: 0, two: 0, three: 0)
loadData()

func loadData() {

   for dict in arrayOfDictionaries {

        for (key, value) in dict {

             if key == "photo" {
                 self.collection!.photo = value as! String
                 arrayToDisplay += [key: value]
             }

             else if key == "id" {
                 self.collection!.id = value as! String
                 arrayToDisplay += [key: value]
             }

             else if key == "one" {
                    ...
```

One problem I have encountered is that the "key" does not change when it changes from one dictionary to the next.

Any help?
Thanks

Comment: Not sure...it seems as if your `arrayToDisplay` should be a `[Collection]`, assuming you want each cell in your table to be represented by a different `Collection` object.

Comment: This is pseudo code. Can you provide code that I can actually try?

Answer (score 1):

I was able to solve this with a switch clause

```
func loadData() {

    for dict in arrayofDict {

          for (key, value) in dict {

                switch key {

                case "photo":
                ...
                case "id""
                ...
          }
```

Hope this helps someone!

Answer (score 0):

I made a little tester class to try this out. Seems to be working fine. Maybe I don't understand what you expect it to do.

```
class ArrayDictTest {
    // data from previous controller, data is there
    var arrayOfDictionaries = [[String: AnyObject]]()
    var arrayToDisplay = [String: AnyObject]()

    func setup() {
        arrayOfDictionaries.append(["photo" : "some photo 1", "id" : "199"])
        arrayOfDictionaries.append(["photo" : "some photo 2", "id" : "299"])
        arrayOfDictionaries.append(["photo" : "some photo 3", "id" : "399"])
    }


    func loadData() -> [String]
    {
        // capture what happened
        var toReturn = [String]()
        for dict in arrayOfDictionaries {

            for (key, value) in dict {
                print(key)
                toReturn.append(key)
                if key == "photo" {
    //                self.collection!.photo = value as! String
                    arrayToDisplay[key] = value
                }

                else if key == "id" {
    //                self.collection!.id = value as! String
                    arrayToDisplay[key] = value
                }
            }
        }
        return toReturn
    }
}

let mytest = ArrayDictTest()
mytest.setup()
mytest.loadData()
```

What is the collection for?

Answer (score -1):

remove else

```
if key == "photo" {
    self.collection!.photo = value as! String
    arrayToDisplay += [key: value]
}

if key == "id" {
    self.collection!.id = value as! String
    arrayToDisplay += [key: value]
}
```

Comment: I had tried that initially. Neither works unfortunately but thanks for advice

Comment: i tested it myself, everything worked fine, did you check if data from previous controller filled arrayOfDictionaries correctly? print arrayOfDictionaries in viewWillAppear before calling loadData() and see if it contains all the keys you're excepting

Comment: Hi Sameh, set the arrayOfDictionaries prints fine. Any idea where my code is wrong? Thanks!